# Appending dictionaries created by a for loop into a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
class Word():
    def __init__(self, chosen_word=''):
        self.chosen_word = chosen_word   
 
   
    def create_list_dict(self):
        letter_list = []
        letter_list = list(self.chosen_word)
        print(letter_list)
        letters_dict = {}
        for letters in letter_list:     
            letters_dict['letter'] = letters
            letters_dict['guessed'] = False            
            print(letters_dict)
            complete_list = []
            complete_list.append(letters_dict)
            print(complete_list)


hello = Word('hello')

print(hello.create_list_dict()
```

currently have this code but it prints out separate dictionaries and lists for each of the letters and I want to create a list of dictionaries from each letter in a given word. Any suggestions?

Comment: It's usually helpful to explicitly show the final value you are trying to make. It seems like you just want the single line: `return [{'letter': letter, 'guessed': False} for letter in self.chosen_word]`

Comment: You need to create a new `letters_dict` each time through the loop. Otherwise you're just appending the same dictionary repeatedly.

Comment: I would love the final result to be:   [{letter: h, guessed: false}, {letter: e, guessed: false}...] etc for all of the letters in any given word

Answer (score 1):

```
class Word():
    def __init__(self, chosen_word=''):
        self.chosen_word = chosen_word

    def create_list_dict(self):
        letter_list = []
        letter_list = list(self.chosen_word)
        #print(letter_list)
        letter_dict = {}
        complete_list = []

        for letter in letter_list:
            letter_dict = {f'letter {letter}': f'guessed {False}'}
            complete_list.append(letter_dict)

        return(complete_list)

hello = Word('hello')

print(hello.create_list_dict())
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Mark's solution is good. Getting to data is more simple with that solution:

Example getting the 2nd letter data:

```
complete_list = hello.create_list_dict()
print(complete_list[1]['letter'])
print(complete_list[1]['guessed'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
class Word():
    def __init__(self, chosen_word=''):
        self.chosen_word = chosen_word

    def create_list_dict(self):
        complete_list = []
        letter_list = list(self.chosen_word)
        for letters in letter_list:
            letters_dict = {}
            letters_dict['letter'] = letters
            letters_dict['guessed'] = False
            complete_list.append(letters_dict)
        print complete_list


hello = Word('hello')

print(hello.create_list_dict())
```

Output :

```
[{'guessed': False, 'letter': 'h'}, {'guessed': False, 'letter': 'e'}, {'guessed': False, 'letter': 'l'}, {'guessed': False, 'letter': 'l'}, {'guessed': False, 'letter': 'o'}]
```

Comment: close to what I'm looking for just each 'letter' in the list should correspond to each letter in the word provided.

Comment: @ElyTrendell, Ahh my bad. I just edited my code and O/P